# Create-React-App + Heroku: Development, Staging and Production environments

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm developing an app (front-end app that consumes an API) based on the create-react-app package. I'm using Heroku to deploy and currently have two deployments based on the same codebase, staging and production. These deployments should use different development/staging/production APIs that have different databases.

Is it possible to tell create-react-app to use different env variables based on how I run `react-scripts start`?

- env.development

  - `REACT_API: https://localhost/react_api`
- env.staging

  - `REACT_API: https://myappstagingapi.heroku.com`
- env.production

  - `REACT_API: https://myappproductionapi.heroku.com`

How would I do this? And is this a good workflow?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar situation having more environments than `production` and `development` while deployment was done automatically from Github.

First of all, make sure you are using the deployment buildpack i.e.
https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git

You can add this URL in Settings in your project on Heroku, replacing NodeJS default buildpack for instance.

Full documentation is here:
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/nhutphuongit/create-react-app-buildpack

If you follow the link above, you can see the chapter **Environment variables**. So, in order that your React App can process custom variables:

1. Add a one that suits you with `REACT_APP_` prefix to your Heroku project environment variables (through *Settings* in Heroku Dashboard) Note that only the envs with this prefix will be visible in your `process.env` later so you should amend your code accordingly
2. Redeploy the application.

This should make the things work. I am sure it is also possible to keep `.env` file but I prefer to have more control via Heroku Dashboard.